# Out of memory Socket.IO rendering Android application

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io

I get the following error on android:

```
Out of memory: Heap Size=41159KB, Allocated=33002KB, Limit=49152KB
```

when I try to call a constructor's `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` method:

```
public class Background {

private Bitmap bitmap;

public Background(Resources resources) {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ground);
}

public void render(Canvas canvas, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {

    for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x += bitmap.getWidth())
        for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y += bitmap.getHeight())
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);

}

}
```

Any solutions?

Before I got this same error when I tried to do this:

```
  socket.on("render", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            update(args);
            Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
            draw(canvas);
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    });
```

using socket.io I created the render loop on a server which emits the "render" event to all client sockets. Now it doesn't even get to the point where it should render itself.

So up above are mentioned two problems, any ideas how to fix this???
Thank You in Advance...

**EDIT**

android:largeHeap="true" just pushed away this issue maybe 10 seconds later

**EDIT 2**

System.gc() make it last even longer, like 15 seconds till it fails with:

```
14 21:01:21.340 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 516182-byte allocation.
06-14 21:01:21.340 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/dalvikvm: Out of memory: Heap Size=130567KB, Allocated=116497KB, Limit=49152KB
06-14 21:01:21.340 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/dalvikvm: Extra info: Footprint=130567KB, Allowed Footprint=130567KB, Trimmed=0KB
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash: crash in the same process: EventThread
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=130567KB, Allocated=116497KB)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:432)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:642)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:663)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at java.util.Formatter.toString(Formatter.java:935)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1998)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1972)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.parser.Parser$Decoder.decodeString(Parser.java:231)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.parser.Parser$Decoder.add(Parser.java:148)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Manager.ondata(Manager.java:339)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Manager.access$1100(Manager.java:19)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Manager$2.call(Manager.java:312)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:482)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket.access$800(Socket.java:29)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:285)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:121)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Transport.onData(Transport.java:113)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket.access$100(WebSocket.java:19)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket$1$3.run(WebSocket.java:74)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at com.github.nkzawa.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:75)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-14 21:01:21.470 12844-18714/com.main.fishyio E/AndroidRuntime_3_crash:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Though I'm not rendering sprites yet...

**EDIT 3**

Running a render loop in separate thread didn't help. So I tried not to draw background and foreground but it also fails. So as I said earlier, the problem seems to be in Socket.io library when I'm trying to run rendering loop on a server.

**EDIT 4**

If I change FPS on server to equal 1 it doesn't fail!!!

Comment: To the looks of it this is a huge loop statement you are trying to achieve. What is it that you are trying to achieve? First, the canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null); is probably being called way too many times.

Comment: i am trying to draw 500x500 image into the 5000x5000 world twice but it seems that problem is with socket.io library if I call render 30 times per second hmm?

Comment: Is that happening on the Main Thread or are you running it it in a separate thread?

Comment: Main :D should I run it on separate? this will fix the problem??? if yes then I owe you big thanks...

Comment: Running on a seperate thread may help but the issue looks like you are trying to do too much to accomplish your goal. Esp for two images. What exactly are you trying to draw?

Comment: I am trying to draw bottom of the water (PNG Image 500x500) on a 5000x5000 big world then I want to draw fishes and some food and after all I want to draw a water (again PNG Image 500x500) on 5000x5000 big world. In browser using javascript canvas it is drawn without any problems. On android it looks like a big deal... and it all should run at 30 FPS... but as I say the problem seems to be in Socket.IO library cause the Out of memory error is thrown many times in exactly in their library's code